# No database selected in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made this function to take values from the form and overwrite the config/database.php.

```
 function configure_database() {
        // write database.php
        $data_db = file_get_contents('./uploads/database.php');
       // session_start();
        $data_db = str_replace('%DATABASE%',    $_SESSION['dbname'],    $data_db);
        $data_db = str_replace('%USERNAME%',    $_SESSION['username'],  $data_db);
        $data_db = str_replace('%PASSWORD%',    $_SESSION['password'],  $data_db);
        $data_db = str_replace('%HOSTNAME%',    $_SESSION['hostname'],  $data_db);
        file_put_contents('./application/config/database.php', $data_db);
        $this->run_blank_sql();
      }
```

and it successfully `overwrites` the `config/database.php`. at the last of the `function` I have written the `$this->run_blank_sql();` which calls the `run_blank_sql()` I have written this `function` to run the `SQL` in `uploads` directory.

```
function run_blank_sql() {
    $this->load->database();
    // Set line to collect lines that wrap
    $templine = '';
    // Read in entire file
    $lines = file('./uploads/install.sql');
    // Loop through each line
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
      // Skip it if it's a comment
      if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
        continue;
      // Add this line to the current templine we are creating
      $templine .= $line;
      // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query so can process this templine
      if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';') {
        // Perform the query
        $this->db->query($templine);
        // Reset temp variable to empty
        $templine = '';
      }
    }
  }
```

But it gives me that error.

[image]

the `configure_database()` overwrites these values successfully.

```
'hostname' => '%HOSTNAME%',
    'username' => '%USERNAME%',
    'password' => '%PASSWORD%',
    'database' => '%DATABASE%',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

To

```
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => *****,
'database' => 'studentPortal',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```

Comment: you have plenty of code here but I don't see the rows that are causing the error. Post the relevant code please

Comment: Ok. Simply look at this function run_blank_sql(). in this $this->load->database(); not working here. I want to Install SQL which will create the table in DB but it says no DB selected.

Comment: You need to read https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html#manually-connecting-to-a-database - you can pass an array of config options and then load the database. I think you're trying to amend the config file which is not the correct way of doing it.

Comment: $data_db = str_replace('%DATABASE%',    $_SESSION['dbname'],    $data_db); Add a log and see $data_db the variable that you've overwritten.

Comment: @Harshana it successfully overwrites the DB name in the config/database.php.

Comment: @Harshana and the DB name is right also.

Comment: property name also correct in new configuration right? as "database"

Comment: @Harshana Yes it also right.

Comment: What is the version you're using and is that supports mysqli?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190489/discussion-between-harshana-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are running the `drop` (I don't see that in your code) is the problem. You're dropping a table but are not specifying the schema where that table is.

Even if you have only one table called `category` you need to be specific about what schema it lives in. Change your `drop` statement to be: `drop table schema.category`.

This hasn't got anything to do with the `$db['default']['database'] = "YOUR_DB";` in the configuration. It's just standard SQL

Answer (score -1):

It says clearly in
[image]
 that  `No Database Selected`

---

I think, You need to specify

```
$db['default']['database'] = "YOUR_DB";
```

in `/application/config/database.php`

Comment: DB is successfully connected. but this statement not working $this->load->database();

Comment: In application/config/autoload.php add this :

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); // add database in array